# JQuery UI datepicker control defaults to Feb. 19 1970 on an iPod Touch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have the following code controlling a JQuery UI datepicker control using JQuery 1.7.1 and JQuery UI 1.8.17. The default date works correctly on all devices except an iPod Touch where the default date is Feb. 19 1970. Has anyone else seen this or possibly found a fix for it? Thanks for any help.

```
$("#beginDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a `Date` object set to today's date instead:

```
$("#beginDate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, it still defaults to 1970, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You should try DateBox:

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

it's a plugin for jQM

Comment: Sadly when I navigate to that site to try out the samples the same thing happens. I would bet it's based off the same JQuery UI datepicker. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Please update your question with more example code you have tried

Comment: To clarify when I navigate to http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ from the iTouch and click the image in the datepicker to select a date the default date is still 1970, this is not an adjustment to my code but the example that is on the dev.jtsage.com site. I'm starting to think this is a limitation/bug int he datepicker control or perhaps the browser on the iTouch.

Comment: I've used DateBox before and you can set the date to whatever, can you please share you demo site link? what version of jQM are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately no this is currently an internal site. I would be curious to know if when you navigate to dev.jtsage.com on your iTouch if this problem does not happen for you. If that's the case then I think it's safe to say something in the iTouch browser/version I have is causing this issue. Again thanks much for your input, I have also used this datepicker control on a PhoneGap app and really like it.

Comment: Just tested on my iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1 and it works as expected. I navigated to this page http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/calbox.html and clicked all inputs, a calendar popped up, selected a date and it displayed correctly